# How can I specify the bundle name in metro with metro.config.js?

Tags: expo, microsoft-metro, react-native-web

I am developing an app for iOS,Android and web using Expo SDK49 with metro.

Metro creates a dist folder for me where the bundle JS file is located under bundles. It is currently called web-[random-id].js.

But I need a specific name for the bundle file? How is this possible?!

The equivalent to this in webpack would be:
config.output.filename = 'bundlename.js'